# If matrix $X$ is sparse, does it mean that $e^X$ is also sparse?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, exponentiation

Let's say, that we have a sparse matrix $X$. Then, is $e^X$ also sparse?

At first glance I would say, that it is not always true, because we could expand this function in Taylor series and I think, that consecutive powers of matrix $X$ do not have to be sparse.

Comment: Your argument is correct but incomplete: you still have to exhibit an example of a sparse matrix whose powers are dense. Separately, here is another thing to think about: suppose $X$ is such that its powers are also sparse (e.g. it is a permutation matrix). Is it still possible for $e^X$ to be dense?

Comment: How exactly are you defining "sparse matrix"?

Comment: Since $e^X$ is defined in terms of power of $X$, you cannot expect it to be sparse unless $X$ is "very" sparse like (block) diagonal. For example, if $X$ is irreducible, $e^X$ is dense.

Comment: Algebraic Pavel's comment has cut right to the chase.

Comment: Counterexample: if $X$ is zero except for $1$s along the superdiagonal, then $e^X$ is upper-triangular with all nonzero entries along and above the diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter example :
\begin{align*}
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

We can compute
\begin{align*}
M^2=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

and so
\begin{align*}
M^p=M^{p \text{ mod }2}
\end{align*}

This gives
\begin{align*}
e^M &= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!} + \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cosh(1) & \sinh(1)\\
    \sinh(1) & \cosh(1)
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Which is not sparse.

Comment: Sorry, just to see if I understand correctly the definition of sparse. In the example, $M$ is 2by2 matrix with the opposite diagonal 1 and everywhere else 0. So Let $M_n$ be the n by n matrix with opposite diagonal 1 and everywhere else 0, then the ratio of no_zero entry to the size of the matrix as n tends to infinity is zero. And that is why $M$ is sparse?

Comment: Well I don't know the definition of sparsity of the OP. I just gave an example for 2 by 2 matrices. The thing is that I cannot generalize this argument to higher dimensions as is since we need that the $n$th power of the matrix is equal to $I$ while keeping the $n$th first power different. This means the eigenvalues would be $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$. I could not find such a matrix.